# Linux command to fetch line count from pgp file

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a requirement to fetch the line count of .pgp file.
I know for normal file we can use this below command:

```
sshpass -p 'pswd3@' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc@qa4.unix.gsm1900.org tail -n +1 /var/test/data_20201202010002.txt.pgp | wc -l
```

But for.pgp file we need to decrypt and count the lines. Can anyone please help to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood currectly, your question is how to decrypt a .pgp file, well first of all, you'll need the encrypter's key to decrypt your file.

Your `key.asc` needs to be like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
...
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Encrypter needs to give you their private key in case for you to decrypt your file:

```sh
# Encrypter
$ gpg --armor --export-secret-keys email@domain.com > yourname.asc
```

Once they gave you `yourname.asc`, you'll need to import the key:

```sh
# Decrypter
$ gpg --import yourname.asc
```

Then decrypt the message:

```sh
$ gpg --output ./decrypt.txt --decrypt ./encrypt.pgp
```

Then count the lines:

```sh
$ wc -l decrypt.txt
126 decrypt.txt
```